# JSON Array request cannot be applied error about constructor

Tags: java

Please help me to fix this code , i"m a new programmer and start learn java at android studio. here the code . i have fixed it but not complate . so many problem

```
    private void request()
{
    Log.d("VOLLE------","MAUKKKK");
    JsonArrayRequest requestItem = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            OurData item = new OurData();
                            item.setId(data.getString("idperawatan"));
                            item.setmText1(data.getString("nama"));
                            item.setmText2(data.getString("alamat"));
                            item.setmImageResource(data.getString("image"));
                            mList.add(item);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
    });
    requestQueue.add(requestItem);
}
```

Comment: Hello! You should at least explain what the code is intended to do and what error do you get. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's complaining about mismatched arguments in `JsonArrayRequest()`. Try removing the POST method and JSONArray arguments and pass the url String as the first parameter:

```
private void request() {
  Log.d("VOLLE------","MAUKKKK");
  JsonArrayRequest requestItem = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
          new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
              for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                  JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                  OurData item = new OurData();
                  item.setId(data.getString("idperawatan"));
                  item.setmText1(data.getString("nama"));
                  item.setmText2(data.getString("alamat"));
                  item.setmImageResource(data.getString("image"));
                  mList.add(item);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
              });
            }
          },
          new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
          });
  requestQueue.add(requestItem);
}
```